# How to execute SQL from Dataflow Streaming job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I need to create a dataflow streaming pipeline in GCP with these requirements.

1. Read data from Kafka and do streaming insert to a table say table1 in bigquery.
2. Do an SQL operation in bigquery from the dataflow job in such a way that table1 will be
   joined to another table table2 and get some attributes from table2.
3. Write the output to another Kafka topic.
   I need to ensure that this SQL is running on the bigquery table on every 2 minutes. I also need to ensure that if the first SQL is processing say records 1 to 100 in table1, the second SQL should not process those records. For that I need to wait the second SQL to get executed once the first SQL is finished. How can I achieve this in any language either Java/Python?